# R - Some Basic Data Manipulation (Populate Column Headers and Grab Data By Date)

Tags: r

I am importing from a csv, and I need some help grabbing the data that I need. Essentially, it is a csv file containing investment returns, and each investment has two columns (One with the date, and one with the returns). The format of the columns are below:

```
Investment1     Investment2 
6/1/2013    -0.043  1/1/2014    0.08
7/1/2013    0.003   2/1/2014    0.01
8/1/2013    0.14    3/1/2014    -0.09
9/1/2013    0.09    4/1/2014    0.015
10/1/2013   0.03    5/1/2014    0.03
11/1/2013   0.02    6/1/2014    0.05
12/1/2013   0.04    7/1/2014    -0.15
```

As you can see, the investment returns are from oldest to newest (Not all investments returns start at the same date), however, all investments contain data for at least the last 12 months. I am trying to accomplish two things here:
1.) Auto populate the "Return" column header with the header from its preceding column and add " Returns" to it. I suppose the expected outcome would look like the below:

```
Investment1 Investment1 Returns Investment2 Investment2 Returns
6/1/2013    -0.043  1/1/2014    0.08
7/1/2013    0.003   2/1/2014    0.01
8/1/2013    0.14    3/1/2014    -0.09
9/1/2013    0.09    4/1/2014    0.015
10/1/2013   0.03    5/1/2014    0.03
11/1/2013   0.02    6/1/2014    0.05
12/1/2013   0.04    7/1/2014    -0.15
```

2.) I need to grab the prior 12 months worth of data per security.So the ending file would look like the above data, but only for Feb 2015 - Jan 2016

I would post some code, but I have no idea where to begin other than reading in the csv file. Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do in the first place and then your jargon (ie, you throw security in there randomly at the end) confuses me even more. This is one reason why posting your code is extremely preferred

Comment: Can you show us the expected outcome?

Comment: Shoot, sorry "Security" is another name for investment.

Answer (score 0):

To change the column names, you could do something like:

```
dat <- read.csv(file = "file", header = T)  
names <- colnames(dat)  
names[2] <- names [1]  
names[4] <- names[3]
colnames(dat) <- names
```

You can also enter your own column name, e.g.:

```
colnames(dat)[2] <- "Investment 1 Return"
```

Comment: If the file is constantly changing (New Investments), is it possible to loop through every other column and take the prior columns name and and " Returns"?

Comment: You could create a "for" loop using something like names[i + 1] <- names[i] or a nested "for" loop using something like dat[i] in the first loop, then the names[i] nested within it.  To add "Returns" you can do names[i + 1] <- paste(names[i] + "Returns")

Comment: This code is complete bogus, but here is my starting point. Can you tell me where I am going wrong?                                                     Raw.Data <- read.csv("C:/Temp/Data.csv", header=T,sep=",")
for(i in names(Raw.Data)){
  names[i+1] <- c(names[i])
  [i] <- i+2
}

Comment: Oh my previous comment was probably misleading: names was a variable I defined as names <- colnames(dat).  You could change "names" in your bogus code to "colnames."